# Python modules not installing

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, pip, python-module

I had some code that was running just fine, and over the course of the day, I broke something, and now I cannot install any python modules. Specifically, I need numpy, matplotlib, and pillow. I cannot install any of them.

But the weird part is that they both appear to install just fine:

```
$ sudo pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.11.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (15.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.3MB 94kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.11.0
```

Or when I try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  python-nose python-numpy-dbg python-numpy-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-numpy
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,763 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,598 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package python-numpy.
(Reading database ... 221259 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-numpy_1%3a1.11.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-numpy (1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up python-numpy (1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1) ...
```

I am using python 2.7, and I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 12 2016, 13:11:58) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>
```

It does this for any module I try and install. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the outputs of `which python` and `sudo pip -V`?

Comment: pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: Could it be you have multiple Python installations and just installed numpy to one of them?

Comment: that is what I was thinking, but, i am unsure how to verify this. I tried to uninstall python, but I ended up removing some `ubuntu-desktop` dependencies along with it.

Comment: Try installing with `python -m pip install numpy` to ensure that your versions of `pip` and `python` are pointing to the same location.

Comment: This is what I got when I did that: `/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip`

Comment: That means your default `python` has no `pip` installed. Follow the instructions in the [installation guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) to get `pip`, and then rerun `python -m pip install numpy`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: @MckaySmalley happy to help. If you'd like, I can write this up as an answer for you to mark as accepted.

Comment: @jonafato, sounds good to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of the default `python` and the default `pip` not matching up. To ensure that packages are being installed to the correct location, use:

`python -m pip install $PACKAGE`

This results in running the `pip` assigned to the desired `python` rather than the first one found in your path.